# Input month and year range in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create windows forms based application which accepts details set of two parameters, month and year wise. The user has the choice to select year and months dynamically and then based on those parameters there will be report generated without database.

Can anybody suggest how to accept parameters on month and year range (eg- range is Jan 2015 to Jan 2016 then user can input values range from Jan 2015,Feb 2015,.........,Jan 2016) and then based on both parameters there will be report ?

Comment: Why it is tagged `asp.net` if you have to create a window form?

Comment: Dear Shekhar you can suggest solution on both currently I have not decided to ho with windows form or asp.net whichever solution I get I will procedd accordingly..

Comment: Where is you data from which you want to create report and in which format your data is?

Comment: Data will be inputs and there will be calculation in the form of %,+,- etc only  like a salary sheet sheet based on base salary there HRA,and allowances etc..

Comment: its a very broad question, what do you have and what do you need help on

Comment: Here is smaller version <b>"How to accept details set of two parameters, month and year wise dynamically over a date range selected by user?"</b>

Comment: i suspect the answer is simple but I honestly can't figure out what you're asking for. Can you give an actual example?

Comment: ok if user selects start as -> Jan 2016 and end as -> Jan 2017 then there will be two text boxes accept inputs for Jan'16,Feb'16.......upto Jan'17 . Hope now it is clear...like for each month two text boxes....

Comment: It requires more effort form your side. You don't just decide what kind of technology to use - ASP.NET or WinForms -  because of the user control!!!

Comment: @bozhidar-stoinev can you suggest for any one technology that will help more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery datepicker and restrict the year to only 2015-2016.

Here is the sample code:

```
<p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</p>

$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: '2015:2016',
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

**Note**: if you want only month and date you can simply create a drop down menu and hardcode the option. I am not sure what you are asking though :)

Here is the Fiddler link:

https://jsfiddle.net/v2verma1990/zsz8Lgb2/

**After edit** I think what you need is dynamic text box to display month and year. See this code:

```
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
        return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox"  class="dynamic"  type="text" value = "' + "mymonthname" + '" />' +
            '<input name = "DynamicTextBox1"  class="dynamic"  type="text" value = "' + "myYearname" + '" />' +
                '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
        }
        function AddTextBox() {
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
        }

        function RemoveTextBox(div) {
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
        }

    //    function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
    //        var values = "vishal";
    //        if (values != null) {
    //            var html = "";
    //            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    //                html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
    //            }
    //            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
    //        }
    //    }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div id="TextBoxContainer" style="text-align: center;" class="step" >
    </div>

        <div>
        <div style="text-align: center;" id="setPrinteraxcis1">
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" class="ANPClass"/>
    </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**P.S.**: I have added input to textbox as string,you can get that from any other source (e.g textbox1.text)and this is called on button click, modify it as needed.

Comment: why downvote?any suggestion?

Comment: The problem statement is how to generate two textboxes dynamically for each month for selected date range... And I didn't downvote... :P

Comment: I could not see that user wants a textbox,its just says user can input values between range.Well,no issues...may be I didnt read the question properly :) my bad

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Your code is correct but I like to notice that in asp.net the asp input controls are not have the same id when they render, from the other hand you use normal input html controls that this means that to get the values on code behind you need to use the FORM, and also you need to disable the validation of the page because will not let you add them.

Comment: Also you use jQuery that is not tagged on question, anyway because the question is general, let it be...

Answer (score 1):

For both WinForms and ASP.NET the approach is similar but the controls are way different.

However, there are DateTimePicker in the toolbox for Windows Forms application. It has `Format` property which you need to set to `Custom`. Then another property - `CustomFormat` - needs to be set to something like `MM-yyyy` to display and give the user opportunity to select just months and years.

If you go with ASP.NET this means you need an HTML based control to do the job. There are tonnes of these and they're free. I personally use Twitter Bootstrap or jQuery UI. There are add-ins for both.

Comment: Plz mention any for ASP.NET addins so that I can Inplement....

Comment: I did. Open up a browser and type "bootstrap datetimepicker". See what happens? :)

Comment: My question is how to generate dynamic text boxes for the each month selected not the date picker part you have posted...

Comment: What is "dynamic text box"? The text box gives a user ability to input whatever he/she wants. It's pretty dynamic already. Maybe you'd like a drop-down box? One with the 12 months and another for set of years? Is this the question?

Comment: Dude I want 2 text boxes for Jan'16,2 for Feb'16... etc in that way ... based on date range that what I am asking ....